# Setting CSS style from local storage when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to set a value stored in local storage when the page is refreshed. The value shows in the local storage but when I set the value to a class it doesn't change. Any reason why? The code below takes a value from a range input and sets the opacity to a class called bars. I want to set it to the value

```
var opacity = localStorage.getItem('opacity');

$('#opacity').on('input', function() {
    $('.bars').css('opacity', $(this).val());
    localStorage.setItem('opacity', document.getElementById('opacity').value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're only setting the style on input, not when the page loads:

```
var opacity = localStorage.getItem('opacity');
if (opacity) {
    $(function() {
        $('.bars').css('opacity', opacity);
    });
}
```